# how to find continuous series using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i am a pl/sql programmer and facing a problem in finding continuity in series for the same date
suppose i am having  series like

1000,1001,
1002,1003,
1004,1005,
1016,1017,
1018,1019,
1020,1021,
1035,1036,
1037,1038,
1039,1040

and i am looking for the output as

```
from_series ------------- to_series
      1000  ------------- 1005
      1016  ------------- 1021
      1035  ------------- 1040
```

i did trying it with but the problem which i faced is in case

```
SELECT *
FROM  retort_t r
where NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  'X'
        FROM    retort_t
        r.series_NO-ISSUE_NO=1 );

SELECT *
FROM  retort_t r
where NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  'X'
        FROM    retort_t
        ISSUE_NO=r.series_NO+1 );
```

I am getting the result by joining the above two queries in alignment. It's ok for few records but my records are in lac's, it's taking a long time to fetch data from joining these two queries.

please let me the appropriate way to sort out the data in correct interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a simple table structure such as:

```
CREATE TABLE T (x INT);
INSERT INTO T (x) VALUES 
    (1000), (1001), (1002), (1003), 
    (1004), (1005), (1016), (1017), 
    (1018), (1019), (1020), (1021), 
    (1035), (1036), (1037), (1038), 
    (1039), (1040);
```

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to get a static value for sequential numbers, you can then group by this value to get the min and max values in a range:

```
SELECT  MIN(x) AS RangeStart, MAX(x) AS RangeEnd
FROM    (   SELECT  X,
                    X - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x) AS GroupBy
            FROM    T
        ) t
GROUP BY GroupBy;
```

**[Example On SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7686d/2)**

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal, you should kindly accept the answer if appropriate [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: This answer is amazing! It is simple and yet still manages to rack my brain!